# DataGrid's values not updating when source is modified unless double clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro, fody-propertychanged

My DataGrid's values does not seem to update when the values in it is modified.

I have tried:

1. Setting the Mode to `TwoWay`
2. Using `BindableCollection` (from Caliburn.Micro)
3. Using `ObservableCollection`
4. Using a `List`
5. Merging `QuotationViewModel` with `TableViewModel`
6. Adding an item in `Work` and removing it
7. Using `x:Name="Work"` in the DataGrid instead of ItemsSource

TableViewModel.cs

```cs
public class TableViewModel : Screen
{
    [ ... ]
    public QuotationViewModel QuotationViewModel { get; set; }
    public void Update()
    {
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WoodTotal);
        QuotationViewModel.Update();
    }
}
```

TableView.xaml

```xml
<!--Total-->
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=QuotationViewModel}"/>
```

QuotationViewModel.cs

```cs
public class QuotationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly TableViewModel _tableViewModel;

    public QuotationViewModel(TableViewModel tableViewModel)
    {
        _tableViewModel = tableViewModel;
    }

    public BindableCollection<ICanCalculate> Work { get; set; } = App.Config.Work;

    public void Update()
    {
        QuotationRow.CalculateQuotations(_tableViewModel.WoodTotal);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Work));
    }
}
```

QuotationView.xaml

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Work, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Repository: https://github.com/hizamakura/Furniture

As seen in [this](https://chito.ge/2VB8gkb.gif) gif, the value updates when I double click it, it should update without having to double click it. I know that the bindings are correct because when I update Value, say of `Milling` to `0.20`, the `Total` will change to `20%` that of the Mahogany.

Answer (score 0):

I just turned to creating a new `BindableCollection` whenever I want to update it.

```cs
public BindableCollection<ICanCalculate> Work { get; set; } = App.Config.Work;

public void Update()
{
    Work.CalculateQuotations(_tableViewModel.WoodTotal);
    Work = new BindableCollection<ICanCalculate>(Work);
}
```

Last time `CalculateQuotations` was just a method that operates on the same object, therefore the property isn't set again, only the properties inside is changed. i.e. the property is still the same object.
Even if I call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Work))` explicitly it didn't fix it, but this puts a new object and it updates everything.